# Is Android O backward compatible with previous versions of Android?

Tags: android, version, compatibility, backwards-compatibility, android-8.0-oreo

Is the app developed for the new OS being released by Android called  "Android O" (version 8) backward compatible with previous versions of Android?

Comment: are any of the OSs backwards compatible with previous versions of the OS?

Comment: What does it mean for an *operating system* to be backwards-compatible with prior versions of the operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. If your targetsdk is < 26 than your app should work fine in the most cases